# Calculate average amount spent by households using survey weights in R

Tags: r, survey

I have survey data where the average amount spent by each household needs
to be calculated. I am unable to apply survey weights to it, NA are getting introduced
even after writing na.rm = TRUE.

The code I am trying to use is

```
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~e1, strata=~a6,weights=~e54, data=data)
svymean(~c16, dstrat)
```

where e1 is my id, a6 is a grouping where I have sectors like rural and urban, e54
is the survey weight and c16 is the amount variable whose average amount I need to
calculate.

I also tried using another code for the same:

```
St26_3a<- data %>%
  group_by(a6) %>%
  summarise(across(c16, list(PROP = ~weighted.mean(., e54, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

but nothing is working.
I need the result to look something like this:

Average amount spent: Rural_avg, Urban_avg, Total_avg

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: It is essential to share a reproducible piece of your data by `dput(head(data))` so that others can use it to have a clearer view of the problem.

Comment: To elaborate on @AnoushiravanR's comment, it is more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. with easy access to the example data, to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at this post; [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).